# View added but not visible (those components added through Storyboard not visible, but those added through code are)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

**VIEW STRUCTURE**

Am having two views ('Home' view and 'Menu' view as seen below), which I have created using storyboard:

[image]

'Home' view is a table view with 'static' cells. And the Menu view is also a table with 'dynamic' (filled with data fetched from the database) cells.

**THE ISSUE AM FACING**
When the App starts up, I want to show the 'Menu' view, & above it (i.e. hiding it), I want to display the 'Home' view (just like Facebook or Path app does, so that when the Home view is panned/dragged/swiped, the view below i.e. the 'Menu' view is revealed).

I do this in 'viewDidLoad' method of Menu view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.viewControllerHome = [[ViewController_Home alloc] init];
    self.viewHome = self.viewControllerHome.view;
    self.viewHome.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,480.0);
    [self.view addSubview:self.viewHome];                                     
 }
```

The subview 'viewHome' does seem to get added, but it is not visible (though I have set the frame size)! I even tried saying "setVisible = YES" on the view, but in vain. Am saying for sure that it's added, because, am adding an emoticon in the 'Home' view "through code" (using self.addSubview in Home View Controller code). This emoticon is visible!, but not rest of the components which I have designed using Storyboard. See below: the Home view's emoticon is seen in the lower left corner of the page, but the rest of the view is "not visible". When I click on "view1", view2' etc, it's not getting selected, which means that View Home is on top of it, but not visible (I checked this by resizing view Home to various heights).

This is the Storyboard attribute list for the Home View...I think the 'view' connection is not ok...am I right?

[image]

And the View hierarchy in Storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, after more than half a day of struggling!

This is what I did & it works:

```
UIStoryboard *myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
ViewController_Home *viewControllerHome = (ViewController_Home *)[myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_Home"];
```